# Powershell Script to create IIS

Tags: powershell, iis

I have following script to create an basic IIS site which is working

```
New-Website -Name "TestApp1" -Port 80 -IPAddress "192.168.1.222" -HostHeader "testapp1.example.com" -PhysicalPath C:\Powershell\TestCreateFolder1 -ApplicationPool "DefaultAppPool"
```

But I dont have this script working

```
$site_command = "-Name ""TestApp1"" -Port 80 -IPAddress ""192.168.1.222"" -HostHeader ""testapp1.example.com"" -PhysicalPath C:\Powershell\TestCreateFolder1 -ApplicationPool ""DefaultAppPool"""

New-WebSite $site_command
```

I am getting this error

```
-Name "TestApp1" -Port 80 -IPAddress "192.168.1.222" -H
ershell\TestCreateFolder1 -ApplicationPool "DefaultAppP
New-Website : Invalid site name
At C:\powershell\CreateIisSite.ps1:35 char:12
+ New-WebSite <<<<  $site_command
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Web
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Invalid site name
,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.NewWebsiteCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerShell command `New-WebSite $site_command` is interpreting the entire `$site_command` as the name of the website. If you want to use your `New-Website` command as a variable, then try this instead:

```
$site_command = "New-Website -Name ""TestApp1"" -Port 80 -IPAddress ""192.168.1.222"" -HostHeader ""testapp1.example.com"" -PhysicalPath ""C:\Powershell\TestCreateFolder1"" -ApplicationPool ""DefaultAppPool"""
Invoke-Expression $site_command
```

Note that the `New-Website` command is in the variable, instead of starting at `-Name` in your example.

Comment: Is there any other possible way of just keep $site_command in a different variable.

Comment: Yes, you could do this instead: `Invoke-Expression "New-Website $site_command"`